# Установка MinGW-w64-x86_64-gdb-8.3.1 на MSYS2

Tags: c++, mingw, clion, msys2

Установил CLion IDE. Поставил toolchain как стартовый набор для работы. По умолчанию установился дебаггер gdb-9.1-*, а CLion выдает ошибку, что работает с версиям GDB с 7.*-* по 8.3-*. Тут и встал вопрос как установить в MSYS2 соответствующий пакет для MinGW.

Попробовал скачать из репозитория gdb-8.2.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz, и поставить его

```
pacman -U ./gdb-8.2.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Пакет установился, но видимо это пакет не для MinGW, а для самой системы MSYS2, как я понял, т.к. теперь CLion пишет просто "Not Found", а вручную указанный пакет gdb.exe из c:\msys64\usr\bin\ просто не воспринимает.

Что я делаю не так и как быть? :)

Comment: *"это пакет не для MinGW, а для самой системы MSYS2"* Ну дык скачайте правильный пакет. Архив называется `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-8.3.1-3-any.pkg.tar.xz`, искать тут: http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/

Comment: Что ж это за CLion, что он только с такими старыми версиями gdb работает?

Comment: В CLion есть встроенные gdb и clang (bundled), но можно использовать и свои, явно указав путь до них. Подробнее [в доках](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-debugger-options.html). Кстати, выдаёт ошибку означает, что нельзя дебажить или просто выдаёт ошибку, как и с свежими CMake, но всё равно работает?

Comment: @S.H. CLion 2020.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"это пакет не для MinGW, а для самой системы MSYS2"* Ну дык скачайте правильный пакет. Архив называется `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-8.3.1-3-any.pkg.tar.xz`, искать тут: [repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64](http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/)